# get similar tasks in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
```

Now I want to return a list of all tasks which are same . like Two tasks `A and B` are considered similar if all the words in the task A exist in task B or vice versa.

how I can achive this in django orm or any other way to do this ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You could implement a `staticmethod` that would filter the objects in your `Task` model using `title__contains` with the baseline instance's `title`.

Comment: @Rfroes87  new into django sir :(  can you please give example please . it would be highly appreciated

Comment: For some reference [Search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/search/).

Comment: @Rfroes87  I know about this , but issue is If I have 50 tasks , how I will separate them on  basis of similarity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to test this solution right now, but just to give some actual example to what I was saying in the comments, here's my suggestion:

**Add this into your `Tasks` model**

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    @staticmethod
    def find_common_tasks(title, pk=0):
        tasks = Tasks.objects.filter(title__contains=title)
        return tasks.exclude(pk=pk) if pk > 0 else tasks
```

Now you could call the method like this, for example:

```
task = Tasks.objects.get(pk=1)
Tasks.find_common_tasks(pk=task.pk, title=task.title)
```

or just `Tasks.find_common_tasks(title="Some title")`.

Comment: How did it turn out @new1122?